# "Information" described by $\sigma-$algebra

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

This is a homework question from a course "discrete stochastics and information theory" I am working on currently:

'Is $\{\{\}, \{b\}, \{a,c\},\{d,b\},\{a,b,c,d\}\}$ a $\sigma-$algebra over $\Omega = \{a, b, c, d\}$? If not, which elements are missing? What is the "information" described by the correct $\sigma-$algebra?'

I know that the given set is not a $\sigma-$algebra and I also know which elements are missing, namely:
$\{a,c,d\}$ (complement of {b}),

$\{a,b,c\}$ (union of {b} and {a,c}) and

$\{d\}$ (complement of {a,b,c}

What could be the meaning of the "information" described by this $\sigma-$algebra ?

Comment: I guess the question is asking which elements you can separate from each other, and which you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is that the element $a$ and $c$ are both present or absent in the members. There's no way you can construct new members using the operations that changes this.

However we have the element $\{b\}$ and by intersecting the complement of this with the element $\{b,d\}$ we get the element $\{d\}$. From these we can form any combination of absence and presence of $b$ and $d$ in elements.

After adding the missing elements we have that the $\sigma$-algebra should contain unions of selections of $\{a,c\}$, $\{b\}$ and $\{d\}$ (including the empty set arising by selecting none of these).

I'm not sure what they mean by the information mentioned, but the members can be characterized with the information on whether $b$, $c$ (which is equivalent to $a$) and $d$ respectively are members of them (that is three bits of information).

Comment: Both answers are correct and gave useful information. This answer (the first paragraph) was exactly what the lecturer wanted to hear, though he admitted it was not totally clear how to answer the question without further context. So I mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure in which context this question is asked. But maybe this answer could be useful.

Usually when you talk about information in sigma algebra, the notion of time is involved. For example when two players A and B are gambling on the result of two independent coin tosses the sample space $\Omega=\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$. So before starting the sigma algebra $$\sigma_0 = \{ \emptyset, \Omega \}$$ represent the information that the two players have (i.e possible outcomes/events). After the first toss of the coin only certain events in $\Omega$ can happen and thìey have $$\sigma_1 = \{\emptyset, \Omega, \{TH,TT\}, \{HH,HT\}\}$$

$\sigma_1$ includes all events of $\sigma_0$ and the events that are possible after the first toss, and so on for $\sigma_3$.  If player A knows the outcome of the first toss but not player B, then the information player A has is given by $\sigma_1$, and the information player B has is just $\sigma_0$

Observe that $\sigma_0 \subset \sigma_1 \dots$. That is $\sigma_1$ contains more information compared to $\sigma_1$. Observe how the sigma algebra get more detailed with time. At the end of the experiment, they can pin point the event in $\Omega$ that has occurred.

So, generally, a sigma algebra contains all possible events that can be measured. What I mean by measured is that when you conduct the experiment, you are able to determine exactly one of those events (so you know it happened).

Let me know if this clarify something to you.